# BrowserWindow loadURL into sub windows?

Tags: javascript, electron

Just getting started with Electron and I would like to be able to use loadURL to load a page, but without replacing the whole page.

The idea here is how something like partials/templates so I can have consist layouts at the top and bottom, but bring in the changing content into the middle section of my application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the middle section is a series of remote pages, then I think you should look at [Webview](https://github.com/atom/electron/blob/master/docs/api/web-view-tag.md), which is a piece provided by electron for this purpose.

If the middle section is a series of content that you would have locally in your electron app, I recommend using something like [Angular](https://angularjs.org) or [React](https://facebook.github.io/react/) in your app, both of which have SOLID support for updating only a few subsections of your app at a time.

Comment: In this case I'm trying to load a series of remote pages into the section and tried using a Webview; which does seem to be the right tool.  Now I've run into an issue with it that the Webview also brings the remote page in as a smaller size than specified. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35047454/how-to-make-electron-webview-fill-specified-size

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a job for the [webview](https://github.com/atom/electron/blob/v0.36.5/docs/api/web-view-tag.md) custom element.